# API Resource: Object property returns null despite being appearing to be present in object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 API Resources to transform some data. The resource's `toArray` method looks like this:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'building' => [
                parent::toArray($request)
        ],
        'construction' => [
            $this->construction
        ],
        'renovations' => $this->renovations,
        'names' => $this->names
    ];
}
```

Here's how I'm calling the resource in the controller:

```
$data = new BuildingResource(Building::find($buildingId))
```

When I return `$data`, I get the following output:

```
{
    "building": [
        {
            "id": 167,
            "building_id": "470",
            "name": "Pharmacy",
            "from_year": 1929,
            "to_year": 1988
        }
    ],
    "construction": [
        {
            "id": 167,
            "building_id": "470",
            "architect": "Walter Scholer",
            "cost": 175000,
            "materials": "Brick"
        }
    ],
    "renovations": [
        {
            "id": 31,
            "building_id": "470",
            "from_year": 1947,
            "to_year": "",
            "architect": "",
            "contractor": "",
        },
        {
            "id": 32,
            "building_id": "470",
            "from_year": 1989,
            "to_year": "",
            "architect": "Walter Scholer and Associates, Inc.",
        }
    ],
    "names": [
        {
            "id": 183,
            "building_id": "470",
            "displayname": 0,
            "abbreviation": "",
            "name": "Geosciences",
            "from_year": 1970,
            "to_year": 1988
        },
        {
            "id": 184,
            "building_id": "470",
            "displayname": 1,
            "abbreviation": "SCHL",
            "name": "Hall of Student Services",
            "from_year": 1988,
            "to_year": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem I'm having is that I can access all of the properties of this object except for buildings'. `$data->construction`, `$data->renovations`, and `$data->names` all work as expected and return the respective data. However, `$data->building` returns null.

However, when I return `$data->id`, I get the ID from the object in the building array.

Out of desperation, I've tried `$data->building['0']`, `$data['building']`, `$data['building']['0']`--none of them work.

I've also tried explicitly setting the keys and values for the building object (rather than using `parent::toArray($request)` and got the same results.

My aim is simply to get the value using `$data->building->id`, just as I can for the other properties of the returned object.

Thanks.

Comment: You are only showing the json-representation of `$data` can you maybe do a `var_dump($data)` to see if you are dealing with arrays, objects or a mix of both? From what you _want_ to get I would change the `toArray()` to: `"building" => parent::toArray($request),` but I can't really tell without knowing what's passed in and what the `parent::toArray()` and `$request` look like.

Comment: Thanks, @dbrumann. I tried your suggestion and got the same result. I did a var_dump, which returned a lot of Laravel's internal data, but the structure was `Building { resource: { "building": { ... } } }`.

Comment: Isn't that just a simple typo? In the data I can see a `building` field, but you try to access $data->buildings. Read from $data->building instead

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Good catch! I checked the code and it's correct there (i.e., $data->building), so the typo was only in the question (which I've now corrected).